# Proof of Sylow's second and third theorem from Lang's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is the excerpt of the proof of Sylow's theorem from Lang's and some moments of the are unclear to me.

1) In order to prove (ii) they take $H$ to be Sylow $p$-subgroup and it is not obvious to me why any two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate?

2) Is $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup then why it has only one fixed point?

I have spent some hours in order to understand these questions but was not able.

Would be very grateful for detailed help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you don't understand in your first question.  Do you not understand why $H=Q$ in the first sentence you underlined?  Or is it just that you don't understand how to deduce (ii) from $H=Q$?

Comment: @EricWofsey, Sorry for my not well-organized question. Let me clarify it: We want to prove (ii) via (i). Let's take $H$ to be Sylow $p$-subgroup then $H$ is contained in some another Sylow $p$-subgroup, call it $Q$. So we have $H\subset Q$ $\Rightarrow$ $H=Q$ because their order are equal. How it follow from here that any two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument shows that for any $p$-Sylow subgroup $H$, there exists $Q\in S$ such that $H=Q$.  But $S$ was by definition the set of conjugates of $P$, so this means $H$ is conjugate to $P$.  So, this proves that every $p$-Sylow subgroup $H$ is conjugate to $P$, which proves (ii).

Moreover, the argument shows that if $H$ is $p$-Sylow and $Q$ is any fixed point of the action of $H$ on $S$, then $H=Q$.  So, there can only be one such fixed point, namely $H$.

Comment: Dear Eric, right now with your help i have totally got it! Thank you very much for your help! I was thinking in the wrong direction. +1